# Java and send file through socket

Tags: java, sockets

I write a client-server application which will be sending an .xml file from the client to the server. I have a problem with sending large data. I notice that the server can get at most 1460 bytes. When I send a file with more than 1460 bytes the server gets only first 1460 bytes and nothng more. In effect I get uncompleted file. Here is my code:

client send:

```
public void sendToServer(File file) throws Exception
{
    OutputStream output = sk.getOutputStream();     

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*1024];
    int bytesRead = 0;

    while((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer))>0)
    {
        output.write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
    }

    fileInputStream.close();
}
```

server get:

```
public File getFile(String name) throws Exception
{
    File file=null;

    InputStream input = sk.getInputStream();

    file = new File("C://protokolPliki/" + name);
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*1024];

    int bytesReceived = 0;

    while((bytesReceived = input.read(buffer))>0) {
        out.write(buffer,0,bytesReceived);
        System.out.println(bytesReceived);
        break;
    }

    return file;
}
```

Do anyone know what is wrong with this code? Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

Nothing help :(. I google about that and I think its may connected with TCP MSS with is equal 1460 bytes.

Comment: Exactly what type of `OutputStream` does `sk.getOutputStream();` return?  Copy/paste the result of `System.out.println("OS is: " + output);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you call `flush()` on the streams.

---

> A passerby asks: isn't `close()` enough?

You linked to the docs for `Writer`, and the info. on the [`close()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#close%28%29) method states..

> Closes the stream, *flushing it first.* ..

So you are partly right, OTOH, the OP is clearly using an `OutputStream` and the docs for [`close()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#close%28%29) state:

> Closes this output stream and releases any system resources associated with this stream. The general contract of close is that it closes the output stream. A closed stream cannot perform output operations and cannot be reopened.
>
> The close method of `OutputStream` **does nothing.**

(Emphasis mine.)

So to sum up. No, calling `close()` on a plain `OutputStream` will have no effect, and might as well be removed by the compiler.

Comment: 1+, and thanks. I'm no expert on Streams, but shouldn't he also be using buffered streams where possible?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *"I'm no expert on Streams,"*  (whispers) Neither am I, and.. *"but shouldn't he also be using buffered streams where possible?"*  ..I'll leave that to those who are. :)

Comment: well, isn't `close()` enough?

Comment: See: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#close() ("Close the stream, flushing it first.")

Comment: @Eng.Fouad  Not according to my reading of the JavaDocs.  Do you have a link that suggests it is enough?

Comment: From the JavaDoc of OutputStream: The flush method of OutputStream does nothing.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Seems I spent some time preparing a reply that was covered by Tudor's comment, but see the edit in any case.

Comment: Not only close, but also flush does nothing. So couldn't it be just an MTU exceeded problem?

Comment: @Tudor Re. MTU.  Not sure. I'm going to have to stop diving into this thread, as I am way outside my area of expertise.

Comment: Shouldn't you mention in your post that also flushing an OutputStream has no effect?

Comment: @Tudor *"flushing an OutputStream has no effect"*   Good point, somehow I missed that in all the excitement.  Not sure whether to mention it in the post, or delete the entire post as noise.

Comment: Actually this is a strange issue indeed. On another SO question, someone actually had a similar problem and adding a flush on the OutputStream solved it...

Comment: In fact, I think your answer is correct. OutputStream is an abstract class, so there is definitely a subclass being returned by Socket.getOutputStream() whose flush method actually does what it's supposed to. What this means is that your comment about close() not having any effect is now most likely wrong. :)) Confusing situation...

Answer (score 3):

The MTU ([Maximum Transmission Unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit)) for Ethernet is around 1500 bytes. Consider sending the file in chunks (i.e. one line at a time or 1024 bytes at a time).

See if using 1024 instead of 1024 * 1024 for the byte buffer solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Although not relate to your question, the API document said FileInputStream.read returns -1 for end of file. You should use >=0 for the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

In the code executed on the server side, there is a break instruction in the while loop. Therefore the code in the loop will only get executed once. Remove the break instruction and the code should work just fine.